# Getting road type or speed limit from Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to get an idea of the type of road returned in a Google Directions API call - either speed limit, type of road etc. You can get speed limit from Google Premium API if you pay. I'd rather find an alternative way.

In google maps you can style a map to colour the road types:

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                disableDefaultUI: false,
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 52.2053, lng: 0.1218},
                styles: [   {"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#00FF00"}]},
                            {"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ff00ff"}]},
                            {"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffff00"}]},                              
        });
```

So, google maps has the information and can style a map accordingly. The Google Directions API does not return the road type (local/arterial/highway) or the speed limit.
Any ideas on how I can get the information?

Comment: If Google requires you to pay for the information, they're not likely to also provide a free way to get the same information. Are you asking for other sources of the data, or ways to deduce or guess the information from Google's free data?

Comment: HI Anaximander - as they enable you to style a map to show local/arterial/highways without paying, they are happy for that information to be freely available, but the nature of its delivery makes it hard to extract. So perhaps one question is can it be extracted from the response for the map. With regards to speed limits I have to agree with you. Another option would be to look at live travel data ,and see what the average speed is, and use this to categorise the road. Might be a but rough and ready. Yes, I'm also interested in other data sources.

Comment: I believe the road type information is not available via Google APIs. Maybe this [feature request](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/62535946) might be interesting to you. The speed limits are available only for Premium plan asset tracking licenses. Not sure about alternative data sources.